# How to connect to remote MySQL database with JetBrains DataGrip

Tags: mysql, datagrip

I've installed MySQL database server on Ubuntu Server 16.04 virtual machine. I've created a new database called Test:

```
CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS Test;
```

I also created new remote user 'test' and gave him privileges on that database:

```
CREATE USER 'test'@'10.17.6.144' IDENTIFIED BY 'test';
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON 'Test'.* TO 'test'@10.17.6.144;
```

I tried to connect to MySQL database using DataGrip IDE, but failed numerous times. My virtual machine is visible on my local network. I can see its ip and MySQL server on nmap. I also changed 
`bind-address: 127.0.0.1`  to `bind-address: 10.17.6.144` in /etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d/mysqld.cnf. But I still get this message:

> Connection to Test@10.17.6.144 failed.
>
> [HY000][1130] null,  message from server: "Host  is not allowed to connect to this MySQL server"

I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong. Any ideas?

Comment: did you check if your firewall is blocking your connections?

Comment: No, it doesn't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add a grant for the ip address of your client system so that it will be able to connect to mysql.

Comment: But i need to know exact ip of my client. What if i will try to connect from another device ?

Comment: If you know the IP range (for example, a subnet in the office) you can do something like this 
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON * . * TO 'test'@'10.1.1.%';